# stop the cursor blinking in xterm

Tags: xterm

how can i stop the cursor from blinking in xterm? i have put the following into `~.Xresources`:

```
xterm.vt100.blink: false
```

and run

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

but the cursor still blinks when i open xterm from the gnome activities panel. my xterm version is:

```
$ xterm -v
XTerm(278)
```

and clicking `help > about` shows details:

```
GNOME Terminal
3.4.1.1
```

thanks

Comment: By the way, the temporary solution is I think [`printf '\e[2 q'`](https://vt100.net/emu/ctrlseq_dec.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was actually not on an xterm - i was on gnome-terminal. beware that

```
echo $TERM
xterm
```

[does not mean that you are actually on an xterm.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93376/which-terminal-type-am-i-using)

for gnome-terminal the solution is to do:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_blink_mode --type string off
```

Comment: Does this persist across logout/reboot?

Comment: so far it has yes

Answer (score 2):

For a real xterm, the .Xresources entry to stop blinking permanently is

```
XTerm.VT100.cursorBlink:        never
```

If you use `false` instead of `never`, the cursor will not blink in a shell, but it may still blink if you start an editor within the xterm.